# equivalent regular expression to remove all punctuations

Tags: regex, r, perl

In R, to remove punctuation from a string, I can do this:

```
x <- 'a#,g:?s!*$t/{u}\d\&y'
gsub('[[:punct:]]','',x)
[1] "agstudy"
```

This is smart but I don't have tight control about the removed punctuations (imagine I want to keep some symbols in my character). How can I rewrite this `gsub` in a more more explicit way without forgetting any symbol, something like this:

```
gsub('[#,:?!*$/{}\\&]','',x,perl=FALSE)
```

**EDIT**

The difficulty I encountered is how to write the regular expression (I prefer in R) that removes all punctuation characters from x, and keep only # for example:

```
 "a#gstudy"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a negative lookahead assertion:

```
x <- 'a#,g:?s!*$t/{u}\\d\\&y'

gsub('(?!#)[[:punct:]]','',x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "a#gstudy"
```

This in essence tests each character twice, asking once from the preceding intercharacter space whether the next character is something other than a `"#"` and then, from the character itself, whether it is a punctuation symbol. If both tests are true, a match is registered and the character is removed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that I can encounter some performance issue ( I have a huge data set to filter ) with this solution?

Comment: I don't know, but it wouldn't be difficult to compare speeds for `(?!#)[[:punct:]]` and `[[:punct:]]` to learn how much the negative lookahead slows things down.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a negated character class, example:

`\pP` is the unicode character class for punctuations characters.

`\PP` is all that is not a punctuation character.

`[^\PP]` is all that is a punctuation character.

`[^\PP~]` is all that is a punctuation character except tilde.

Note: you can stay in the ASCII range by using `\p{PosixPunct}`:

`[^\P{PosixPunct}~]`

or use unicode punctuations characters with this particularity in the ASCII range with `\p{XPosixPunct}`:

`[^\P{XPosixPunct}~]`

Comment: Interesting+1! How can i use this within R/perl?  For example `gsub('[^p#]','',x,perl=F)` , keep the # but it removes all the other good characters...

Comment: @agstudy: No, `\pP` and `\PP` are character classes as `\w` and `\W` but for punctuation characters. For your example, you must write `[^\PP#]`

Comment: thanks. I am nearly close with `gsub('[^\\PP#]','',x,perl=TRUE)` , I get ` "agstudy#$"` , I don't know why I have the dollar($) at the end. Any idea?

Comment: @agstudy: The reason is that the `$` is not a punctuation symbol for unicode. However if you use the posix version `\P{PosixPunct}` it is different because punctuation characters in ASCII range are defined as follow: "all that is not a controls, spaces or alphanumerics characters.

Answer (score 5):

Reading at [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes) indicates that the `[[:punct:]]` characters should include:

```
[-!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

From the R `?regex` page, we also get this as verification:

```
[:punct:]
Punctuation characters:
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

Thus, you can possibly use that as your basis for creating your own pattern, excluding the characters you want to keep.

---

This is messy as heck especially with two much nicer answers, but I just wanted to show the silliness I had in mind:

Create a function that looks something like this:

```
newPunks <- function(CHARS) {
  punks <- c("!", "\\\"", "#", "\\$", "%", "&", "'", "\\(", "\\)",
             "\\*", "\\+", ",", "-", "\\.", "/", ":", ";", "<",
             "=", ">", "\\?", "@", "\\[", "\\\\", "\\]", "\\^", "_", 
             "`", "\\{", "\\|", "\\}", "~")
  keepers <- strsplit(CHARS, "")[[1]]
  keepers <- ifelse(keepers %in% c("\"", "$", "{", "}", "(", ")",
                                   "*", "+", ".", "?", "[", "]",
                                   "^", "|", "\\"), paste0("\\", keepers), keepers)
  paste(setdiff(punks, keepers), collapse="|")
}
```

Usage:

```
gsub(newPunks("#"), "", x)
# [1] "a#gstudy"
gsub(newPunks(""), "", x)
# [1] "agstudy"
gsub(newPunks("&#{"), "", x)
# [1] "a#gst{ud&y"
```

---

Bleah. Time for me to go to bed....

Comment: thanks +1 for the link. The difficulty here to write (by hand) the regex within gsub. But I will do it!

Comment: @agstudy, the point I was going to edit in is that since we know what characters this class contains, we can probably create our own pattern, maybe using a vector of these characters and `setdiff` or something else.

Comment: yes and no. We should know the symbols , and how to write the regular expression within gsub , `gsub([-!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[/\/\\]^_`{|}~],'',x)` will fail for example. I man, not easy(for me) to write the regular expression here.

Answer (score 3):

It works exactly the same in Perl, `[:punct:]` is a POSIX character class that simply maps to:

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

The equivalent Perl version would be:

```
my $x = 'a#,g:?s!*$t/{u}\d\&y';
$x =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
print $x;

__END__
agstudy
```

Comment: Thanks. The question is not to have the equivalent perl code, but the equivalent regular expression using symbols (by hand).

Comment: Not sure why Perl was tagged then, but the character class just maps to the characters listed above.

Comment: Perl was tagged because , a perl regular expression can be used in R. `grep(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE,..)`

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward approach is to use a lookahead or a lookbehind to match the same character twice, once to make sure it's a punction, and once to make sure it's not "`#`".

```
(?=[^#])[[:punct:]]
```

or

```
(?!#)[[:punct:]]
```

Lookahead and lookbehinds are a little expensive, though. Rather than using a lookaround at every position, it's more efficient to only use one when we find a punctuation.

```
[[:punct:]](?<!#)
```

Of course, it's even more efficient to get rid of lookarounds completely. This can be achieved through double-negation.

```
[^[:^punct:]#]
```

I haven't tested these with R, but they should at least work with `perl=TRUE`.